# 5120x2160 doesn't work with Wayland

Tags: xorg, display-resolution, 22.04, wayland

I have a Framework laptop running 22.04 connected to an external Thunderbolt 3 monitor, an LG34WK95 with 5120x2160 native resolution and 21:9 aspect ratio. When I use the Wayland default, the display settings only give me 3440x1440 as an option for 21:9, causing poorly scaled blurry text. But switching to Xorg fixes this and lets me use the native display resolution properly. Is this a Wayland bug or known limitation? I originally ran 21.04 on this laptop and the native resolution worked out of the box there; this issue only appeared once I upgraded to 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem during the install.  Once the install was completed and I did a "apt full-upgrade" the 5120x2160 resolution worked.

The issue still exists in the 22.04 install image.